# Calculate the AVG based on a formula

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following input :

```json
{
   "_id":"series/cogtech/BertonKHS06",
   "type":"Article",
   "title":"Speech Recognition.",
   "pages":{
      "start":85,
      "end":107
   },
   "year":2006,
   "booktitle":"SmartKom",
   "url":"db/series/cogtech/54023732.html#BertonKHS06",
   "authors":[
      "Andr? Berton",
      "Alfred Kaltenmeier",
      "Udo Haiber",
      "Olaf Schreiner"
   ]
}
```

I want to get the average page numbers by book.

A book has a start and an end page.

To calculate the average :  `AVERAGE=(end - start)/2`
How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$subtract` for minus and `$divide` for devide,

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      average_pages: {
        $divide: [
          { $subtract: ["$pages.end", "$pages.start"] },
          2
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zQLaL7l5-CU)